# Rails: How to save the parent value of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'd like to do is to save the `shop_id` in the `Item` model.

My models are as followings;

**models**

shop.rb

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    has_many :items
    has_many :categories
end
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
    has_many :categories
end
```

**schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160615060137) do

...

  create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "shop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

...

end
```

How can I create controller `new` and `create` to save `shop_id` in `items`?
I can get the parameter such as `Shop.find_by(id: params[:shop_id])`

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

**UPDATE**

When I try @Saad's answer, `NoMethodError` was displayed as below.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_key' for #<Item::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f901e079a30>
Did you mean?  to_query
               to_ary):
  app/views/items/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_items_new_html_erb__3601549985910054210_70128472136980'



NoMethodError (undefined method `to_key' for #<Item::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f901e079a30>
Did you mean?  to_query
               to_ary):
  app/views/items/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_items_new_html_erb__3601549985910054210_70128472136980'
```

The line of new.html.erb:4 is as following (I haven't use partial `_form.html.erb` so far);

```
  <%= form_for(@item, url: shop_items_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
```

**UPDATE2**

`routes.rb` is as below.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  ...

  resources :items,              only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :shops do
    resources :items
  end

  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving the previuos code and assuming you shops and items controller are nested:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_shop

  def index
    @items = @shop.items
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @item.shop = @shop
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to shop_item_path(@shop, @item), notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def load_shop
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
  end

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :shop_id)
  end
end


<%= form_for([@shop, @item]) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :shop_id%>
    <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @DennisCastro. The following error was displayed when I tried your code. `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Shop without an ID):  app/controllers/item_controller.rb:38:in 'load_shop'`. It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: How I said. I think you are using nested controllers, paste your route

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @DennisCastro. I added `routes.rb` at the bottom of my question.

Comment: my code should work, to go to Items controller your link will be /shop/:id/items, if you go to items cotroller by /items the code not works. You need to decide what route use.

Comment: Thank you @DennisCastro. It works! I overlooked the view at the bottom of your answer...

Answer (score 0):

`items_controller.rb`

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
    @items = @shop.items
  end

  def new
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
    @item = Item.new
  end
    def create
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to shop_item_path(@shop, @item), notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @shop = Shop.find params[:shop_id]
      @item = @shop.items.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :shop_id)
    end
end
```

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@item, url: shop_items_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
  <% if @item.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this item from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :shop_id, value: @shop.id %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`index.html.erb`

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @item.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Shop:</strong>
  <%= @item.shop %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_shop_item_path(@shop, @item) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', shop_items_path(@shop) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Sadd. I tried, but it doesn't work. It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.